# Any way to flag users or user profiles?

Tags: discussion, moderation

The user that made me want to do this is the new, 1 rep user https://android.stackexchange.com/users/13173/ (**warning** username NSFW, website link NSFW)

Or is just a case of flagging their post and making a mention of it on Meta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flagging one of their posts and putting a reason in the "other" field should be sufficient to alert a mod. (Obviously posting here works too, but the flag would be preferred.)

I nuked the account from orbit.